# Forcing JFrame to not resize after setResizable(false). Command wont work

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe

I have a simple Atari breakout program, and long story short, one of my powerups is to allow the user to resize the window for a few seconds, then make the window non-resizable again.Everything works fine, and the window goes from being not-resizable, to being resizable for a few seconds. What's supposed to happen, is after the few seconds are up, the window should stop accepting input for resizing the window (IE: should not be resizable). The only problem, is that whenever it's supposed to be set to non-resizable, if you keep your cursor dragging on the window to resize it, it keeps resizing. It will only activate the non-resizable state of the window after you let go of the window. My question, is how do I make this happen before you let go of the window, taking away your control of resizing, once the timer is up?

P.S: I want to program to immediately keep you from resizing the window once the command is called, not waiting for you to let go of the mouse. Any suggestions?

Here is a simplified case: (You are given 6 seconds to resize the window and play with it)

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        JFrame testFrame = new JFrame();
        testFrame.setResizable(true);
        testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        long endingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 6000;
        Timer testTimer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if((endingTime - System.currentTimeMillis()) < 0){
                    testFrame.setResizable(false);
                }
            }
        });
        testFrame.setVisible(true);
        testTimer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Java's `Robot` class to force a mouse release. I've modified your example code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
  JFrame testFrame = new JFrame();
  testFrame.setResizable(true);
  testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  Timer testTimer = new Timer(6000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            testFrame.setResizable(false);
      Robot r;
      try {
        r = new Robot();
        r.mouseRelease( InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
      } catch (AWTException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

  });
  testFrame.setVisible(true);
  testTimer.start();
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly @Quicksilver002 ! It does seem a little inefficient as far as forcefully taking control of the mouse, rather than having the program simply restrict you from resizing it, but so far, this seems to be the only possible way. Either way though, it definitely works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Well one way I could think of is setting the size back after a resizing event if the frame is not resizable.

Not sure how well it would work though.

```
frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        if (!frame.isResizable()) {
            frame.setSize(...);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Good call, @Bubletan!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried revalidating the JFrame immediately after the power up ends? This will most likely solve your issue (though I wouldn't know given that you have neither an SSCCE, or an MVCE). I hope this helps, and best of luck.