# Forcing JFrame to not resize after setResizable(false) not working

Tags: java, swing, resize

I am having a bit of trouble getting this to work. I have created a game in which I have a power up that lets the window be resizable for a few seconds. Everything works fine, and the window goes from being not-resizable, to being resizable for a few seconds. What's supposed to happen, is after the few seconds are up, the window should stop accepting input for resizing the window (IE: should not be resizable). The only problem, is that whenever it's supposed to be set to non-resizable, if you keep your cursor dragging on the window to resize it, it keeps resizing. It will only activate the non-resizable state of the window after you let go of the window. My question, is how do I make this happen before you let go of the window, taking away your control of resizing, once the timer is up?

Here is a simplified case: (You are given 6 seconds to resize the window and play with it)

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        JFrame testFrame = new JFrame();
        testFrame.setResizable(true);
        testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        long endingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 6000;
        Timer testTimer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if((endingTime - System.currentTimeMillis()) < 0){
                    testFrame.setResizable(false);
                }
            }

        });
        testFrame.setVisible(true);
        testTimer.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29321523) or are you asking something different?

Comment: I'm providing the code suggested for quicker and better answers. The first question was poorly worded, and lacked several vital details. It had no supporting code, and thus, had no possibility to properly answer. I would take it down if I could.

Comment: OK.  Have you tried creating a second thread to time the six seconds (or whatever it's supposed to be) and make a note of the size at the end of the time?  Then in the main thread, you could snap the size back to that value when you make it not resizable.  Did you try something like this?

Comment: @David_Wallace   Yes, but it unfortunately didn't work. It does keep it at a single size, but as you drag it, it just glitches up, and every tiny movement or drag you do simply makes it flash between where your cursor is, and the size it's supposed to be at. I tried looking at the source code for the JFrame's setResizable method, but couldn't find any help there, as to what exactly it does behind the scenes. I was thinking about maybe some way to force the user's mouse to let go of the window? Not quite sure.

Comment: No, I mean, have the code to snap the size back _after_ the dragging has finished.

Comment: Instead of posting a new question, you could have edited the old one. Just a heads up for in the future

Comment: @David_Wallace That would work, except I want it to only allow them to resize it for exactly 6 seconds. If they keep their cursor held down, then they can resize it for however long they want. After the resize, I could resize it again, but it'd defeat the purpose. I need it to only resize for 6 seconds, and revoke your permission to resize it after 6 seconds, no matter if you're currently dragging it or not. (What the power up is supposed to do)

Comment: *"I'm providing the code suggested for quicker and better answers."*  You should [edit *that* question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29321523/edit) rather than ask a duplicate.  Voting to close this one.

Comment: I would seriously doubt whether you can get the operating system to interrupt a resize in progress.  This may be operating system dependent, but I think that "resizable" essentially means that you can start resizing the window.  Once you mouse down on the window border, the operating system takes over.  I think the best you can do is snap the window back to a new size after the resize is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Java's `Robot` class to force a mouse release.  I've modified your example code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    JFrame testFrame = new JFrame();
    testFrame.setResizable(true);
    testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Timer testTimer = new Timer(6000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                testFrame.setResizable(false);
          Robot r;
          try {
            r = new Robot();
            r.mouseRelease( InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
          } catch (AWTException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

    });
    testFrame.setVisible(true);
    testTimer.start();
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly @Quicksilver002 ! It does seem a little inefficient as far as forcefully taking control of the mouse, rather than having the program simply restrict you from resizing it, but so far, this seems to be the only possible way. Awesome job, and thank you very much. 

P.S: If you'd wish to, please give the answer you provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29321523/4543762 so others browsing can find a correct answer. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Okay, I posted it there, too.  You can make it more efficient by not creating the Robot every time (obviously).  But I don't think actually using the Robot uses much overhead.